# Lucene: Completely disable weighting, scoring, ranking,

Tags: lucene

I'm using Lucene to build a big index of token co-occurences (e.g. `[elephant,animal]`, `[melon,fruit]`, `[bmw,car]`, ...). I query the index for those co-occurences using a `BooleanQuery` to get an absolute count, how often those two tokens co-occured in my index like so:

```
// search for documents which contain word+category
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("word", word)), Occur.MUST);
query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("category", category)), Occur.MUST);
// only care about the total number of hits
TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
searcher.search(query, collector);
int count = collector.getTotalHits();
```

These queries run very frequently and I'm currently not satisfied with performance. I discovered, that the method `BooleanQuery#createWeight` takes a lot of time. Now, I do not need any scoring or ranking of my results, as I'm interested in absolut documents counts only.

Is there a convenient way (pre-existing class e.g.) to completely disable scoring and weighting? If not, are there any hints which classes I need to extend for my use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if it will bypass scoring in such a way as to get the performance increase you are looking for, but an easy way to apply a constant score would be to wrap the query in a [`ConstantScoreQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreQuery.html), like:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
//etc.
ConstantScoreQuery query = new ConstantScoreQuery(bq);
searcher.search(query, collector);
```

I would, however, *strongly* recommend making use of `Filter`s.  Not only do filters bypass score, they also cache their results,  so your "category" field, particularly, seems like it would be a very good place for this.  The first time you query in a category using a filter, it will take longer as it needs to build the cache for that filter, but after that, you should see a very significant increase in speed.  Take a look at the [`FieldCacheTermsFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCacheTermsFilter.html).

Like:

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("word", word));
Filter filter = new FieldCacheTermsFilter("category", category);
TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
searcher.search(query, filter, collector);
int count = collector.getTotalHits();
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment; I tried out the ConstantScoreQuery, however it seems to delegate most of its functionality to the wrapped Query, so I can achieve no speedup this way. The Filter sounds promising, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Impressive; used the `FieldCacheTermsFilter`, speed feels like 100x now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and came up with this solution which is compatible with Lucene 7.  (Unfortunately the FieldCacheTermsFilter class, and the search method which accepts a filter is not available in Lucene 7).

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReaderContext;
import org.apache.lucene.search.SimpleCollector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UnscoredCollector extends SimpleCollector {
    private final List<Integer> docIds = new ArrayList<>();
    private LeafReaderContext currentLeafReaderContext;

    @Override
    protected void doSetNextReader(LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException {
        this.currentLeafReaderContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsScores(){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void collect(int localDocId) {
        docIds.add(currentLeafReaderContext.docBase + localDocId);
    }
}
```

...and then used the collector when searching

```
UnscoredCollector collector = new UnscoredCollector();
indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
//docId's are now available in the docIds ArrayList in the UnscoredCollector
```